# Calculating probability of results of test

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

There are given following informations: 
The probability that ill person is recognised as ill is $0.64$. The probability that healthy person is recognised as healthy is $0.89$.
The probability of a disease is $P (K) = \frac{3}{40}.$
 
Calculate the probability that a randomly selected test is positive and comes from healthy person.

**My idea and question:**

$A$-ill,$B$-positive Test.

$P(A)=\frac{3}{40}\Rightarrow P(A^{c})=\frac{37}{40}$

$P(A| B)=0.64\Rightarrow P(A^{c}| B)=0.36$

$P(A^{c}| B^{c})=0.89\Rightarrow P(A| B^c)=0.11$

$P(B|A^{c})=?$

$P(P|A^{c})=\frac{P(A^{c}|B)P(B)}{P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^{c}P(A^{c}))}$

But how do I find $P(B|A)$ and $P(B|A^{c})$?

Comment: Basic Bayes' Theorem problem. Many similar problems answered on this site. Recent edits still not a correct start. $P(\text{Pos}|\text{Ill}) = .64,$ called the _sensitivity_ of the test. Etc. Also apparent confusion between notations $A$ and $K$. Wikipedia has nice pages on this.

Comment: See [_Wikipedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem). In drug testing example, your 'Ill' is their 'User'.

Comment: $P(A\mid B)$ is the probability of event $A$ when event $B$ happens.  If $A$ is the event, "the person is ill," and $B$ is the event, "the test turned out positive," then the probability that the test is positive when the person is indeed ill is $P(B \mid A) = 0.64$.  Likewise, $P(B^c \mid A^c) = 0.89$.  What the question asks is $P(B \cap A^c)$.  You need the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Ok, so I should use: $P(B \cap A^{c})=P(B | A^{c})P(A^{c})$. But again I don't have $P(B|A^c)$.

Comment: Yes, and notice that you are given $P(B^c \mid A^c)$, which is the complement of $P(B \mid A^c)$ to 1.